# inserting emojis in database showing ??? for some emojis

Tags: php, sql, database

when i insert emojis in database showing ??? for some emojis my collation in database is utf8mb4_bin i am using XAMPP Version: 5.5.38

[image: database]

Comment: What about the PHP?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` and after this restart `mysql` and re-insert emojis

Comment: it is giving the same result same

Answer (score -2):

You need to change collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for table column(mysql).